# Using $c$ function to calculate $H$ spectrum in bosonic string theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, operators, string-theory, compactification

Ch-$8$ sec-$8.4$ Polchinski (String theory vol I) states

> In the canonical approach, focus on the zero-mode contribution to the world-sheet action. Inserting $$\color{red}{X^m(\sigma)=x^m(\sigma^2)+w^mR\sigma^1}$$
> into the world-sheet action gives $$L=\frac{1}{2\alpha’}G_{mn}(\dot{x}^m\dot{x}^n+w^mw^nR^2)-\frac{i}{\alpha’}B_{mn}\dot{x}^mw^nR$$

Using a quantized value of $p_m$ coming from compactification and constructing $H$ form $L$ we can get discrete spectra of the Hamiltonian which tells us the zero mode energy. The whole magic lies in the decomposition of the red highlighted equation. My doubt is over the motivation to do this particular decomposition.

Comment: Anything else either wouldn't solve the equations of motion or wouldn't be a zero mode.